# Input Validation infinite Loop

Tags: python, loops

```
    groupno = int(input('Please enter the size of group: '))
    while groupno >= 1 or groupno <= 20:
        groupsizes= int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
    g.append(groupno)
```

Ok so once i use this code if i enter a value above 20 or less than one it looped infinitely to enter the correct group size. This also applied to a meal rating system using the same algorithm

Comment: What's the question? I see code but I have no idea what you want to do with it or what could be going wrong.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `groupno` in your while loop

```
while groupno >= 1 or groupno <= 20:
    # groupsizes= int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
    groupno = int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

A value above 20 is also above 1, so the first part of the `or` statement is true.

You want:

```
not ( 1 < groupno < 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Elliot's answer, your while condition looks flawed, you should change it to this

```
while groupno <= 1 or groupno >= 20:
```

Assuming you want a group size between 1 and 20

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
>>> def get_groupno():
...     groupno = 0
...     while not  1 <= groupno <= 20:
...         try:
...             groupno = int(input('Please enter a valid group size: '))
...         except ValueError:
...             continue
...     return groupno
...
>>> get_groupno()
Please enter a valid group size: 100
Please enter a valid group size: 0
Please enter a valid group size: 1
1
```